# setretaininstance(true) doesn't retain its class members using headless fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
Android Studio 1.3 RC 3
```

Hello,

I am trying to retain state of my headless fragment `RetainedFragment.java` through contiguration changes.

Rotation of the devices works ok. However, the problem is in my `MainFragment.java` I `startActivityResult(...)` for a implicit activity (Opening gallary app) to view photos.

The `RetainedFragment.java` doesn't retain its class members, even though I have setRetainInstance(true) in onCreate() of RetainedFragment.java.

I have also tried using the `onSavedInstanceState` to saved the mDataInt to a bundle and retrieve it from the `onActivityCreated` method.

`RetainedFragment.java` is a `headless fragment` so doesn't contain any UI, its just used to keep and restore state.

The thing I can't understand, rotational changes work fine. Its only when I start a new implicit activity to start the gallary app.

The class member I am testing this is called `mDataInt` and I set its initial value to 101 when the class is instantiated. Then to 2015 in the `onSavedInstanceState` to retain that value when the RetainedFragment is re-created. 
Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
public static class RetainedFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = RetainedFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Integer mDataInt = 101;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Ensure the data survives runtime configuration changes */
        setRetainInstance(true);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate savedInstanceState == null - dataInt: " + mDataInt);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        mDataInt = 2015;
        Log.d(TAG, "onSavedInstanceState mDataInt: " + mDataInt);
        outState.putInt("DATAINT_KEY", mDataInt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated mDataint: " + mDataInt);

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated savedInstanceState != null - dataInt: " + savedInstanceState.getInt("DATATINT_KEY"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this has a problem, and I would like to post here to hear from anyone who has some ideas about this.

Under developer options I had enabled `Don't keep activities` I have disabled this option. Now the application works as expected